# Dynamic text/table for bsTooltip hover info

Tags: r, shiny, tooltip

Is it possible to set the text of bsTooltip to be a dynamic text/table/UI?
If not, is there any way to pop-up a dynamic text when hovering over a UI?

Here is a repex:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  valueBoxOutput("value"),
  bsTooltip("value", textOutput("text"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$value <- renderValueBox({valueBox("Value Box text", "Value Box text")})
  output$text <- renderText({"Text"})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Result:
[image: text not appeared properly]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a modal with the help of a bit of JavaScript:

```r
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)

js <- '
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#value").on("mouseover", function() {
    Shiny.setInputValue("modal", true, {priority: "event"});
  })
});'

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$script(HTML(js))),
  valueBoxOutput("value")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$value <- renderValueBox({
    valueBox("Value Box text", "Value Box text")
  })
  
  output$text <- renderText({"Text"})
  
  observeEvent(input$modal, {
    showModal(
      modalDialog(
        textOutput("text"),
        title = "Hello!",
        easyClose = TRUE
      )
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Laurent thanks so much for your comment. I'm trying to prevent popping up a modal that the user has to close. I just want some quick info to be shown to the user with hovering. Do you think it's possible somehow?